# copy a list of set by values in python

Tags: python, reference, set

Here is my code

```
store = [set() for i in xrange(0,5)]
items = store[:]
store[1].add(1)
```

here after line 3 it changes the `items` too

```
print items

output : set([]), set([1]), set([]), set([]), set([])
```

I tried using for loop to go into every element of every set in `store` separately and adding it on `items` after clearing the each set in `items` and got same result

Is there anyway to copy the set above by values not its references, I just need to copy the values of a non empty list of sets and iterate over it again, but since its getting copied by reference my program is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `deepycopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
items = deepcopy(store)

>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = deepcopy(a)
>>> b[1] = 1
>>> print b
[1,1,3]
>>> print a
[1,2,3]
```

> A *deep copy* constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original. (From the deepcopy documentation)

It creates a completely different set of memory spaces and is not a shallow copy that simply points to the same memory space.

Comment: does deep copy works for just numbers in a list too or a namedtuple with a `set` and an `int` as attributes

Comment: @PratyushDhanuka, Updated Answer with explanation and examples. Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 2):

You are only creating a shallow copy of `store`; the referenced mutable sets are not copied.

You'd have to copy each set too:

```
items = [set(s) for s in store]
```

or use the [`copy.deepcopy()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

items = deepcopy(store)
```